# padding beside image while using bootstrap/css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new to web development. I have basic experience with html/css and am using bootstrap to create a website just to kind of teach myself. I want my image to cover the whole page which it does when i decrease the size of the browser but when using full screen it adds padding to the side.

[full screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkQDg.jpg)

i have tried some things to fix it like changing padding to -20px or making overflow-x hidden but can't seem to fix it.

bootstrap code

```
<div id="banner" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-12 nopadding">
            <img src="images/headercopy.jpeg">
        </div>
</div>
```

css code

```
html, body {
    line-height: 1.8;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.nav {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-transparent .navbar-brand {
    color: white; //nightalreadycolor
}

.navbar-collapse .page-scroll {
    color: white; //nightalreadycolor
}

.navbar-transparent .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-transparent .navbar-brand:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #c8e8f4; //light blue
}

.navbar .navbar-transparent .navbar-fixed-type {
    background-color: red;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.nopadding {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.aboutimage {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#about {
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
}

#about p {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: white;
}

#about p img {
    padding-top: 5px;
    outline: solid #f00 1px !important;
}

.container {}

#fleet {
    border-right: thin solid black;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
    background-color: grey;
}

#fleet h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#fleet h2 {
    padding-right: 10%;
    float: right;
}

#rates {
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 600px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #574951;
}

#rates h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#contact {
    text-align: center;
    height: 600px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #574951;
}

#reservation {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 600px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Sorry if some of my code seems to be redundant or inefficient like i said I'm still very new to all of this. If there's any other information you need let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use images as a background. So if it's the `#banner` `div` that you want to fill up, your css will be like this:

```
#banner {
    background-image:    url('images/headercopy.jpeg');
    background-size:     cover;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Then you just have to use this markup:

```
<div id="banner" class="container-fluid"></div>
```

Of course you can set to your css code for the `#banner` the height you want etc.

Comment: That worked! i had tried that before but didn't realize i had to set the height! thanks